# Evaluating $\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac1{4^n(n+1)}\binom{2n}n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

We have $$\arcsin 1 =\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac1{4^n(2n+1)}\binom{2n}n$$

I want to evaluate a similar sum, namely $$\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac1{4^n(n+1)}\binom{2n}n$$

Is there an expression for this?

Comment: According to [WolframAlpha its simply 2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+4%5E(-n)%2F(n+%2B+1)+*+%5Cbinom%7B2n%7D%7Bn%7D+from+n+%3D+0+to+infty).

Comment: Consider $f(x) = \sum \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}{2n\choose n}$. Compute $f'(x)$ in closed form (binomial theorem) and integrate up to get $f(x)$ in closed form and finally take $x=1/4$.

Comment: @Winther How do I evaluate f'? Binomial theorem is not helpful

Comment: [It is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton%27s_generalized_binomial_theorem): $(1+x)^{\alpha} = \sum_{n\geq 0} {\alpha\choose n} x^n$ and ${-1/2 \choose n}$ has a simple relationship with ${2n \choose n}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function $\frac1{\sqrt{1-x}}$. A series representation can be obtained by either computing the coefficients of the corresponding MacLaurin Series or with the help of Newton's generalized Binomial Theorem. Both yield to

> $$\frac1{\sqrt{1-x}}~=~\sum_{n\geqslant0}\binom{2n}n\frac{x^n}{4^n}~~~~~|x|<1$$

Integrating this one over the boundaries of $0$ and $1$ we get

$$\sum_{n\geqslant0}\binom{2n}n\frac{x^n}{4^n(n+1)}=\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{1-x}}$$

> $$\therefore~\sum_{n\geqslant0}\binom{2n}n\frac{x^n}{4^n(n+1)}~=~2$$

The result coincides with the one given by *Sudix* using the generating function for the Catalan Numbers (which can be found in a similiar manner like the given derivation of this particular value).

Answer (score 5):

One possible solution is recognizing a part of your sum as the Catalan-numbers:

$$
C_n = \frac{1}{n+1} \binom{2n}{n} 
$$

Using them, your sum can be transformed into:

$$
\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac1{4^n(n+1)}\binom{2n}n 
=\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac1{4^n}C_n\\
=\sum_{n\ge 0}C_n \cdot x^n \qquad \text{at }x=1/4
$$

The closed form of this generating function is known:

$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n x^n = \frac{2}{1 + \sqrt{1 - 4 x}}
$$

Now, substituting $x=1/4$ yields the result

$$
\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac1{4^n(n+1)}\binom{2n}n = 2
$$

Comment: Thank you, but this begs the question why $\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n x^n = \frac{2}{1 + \sqrt{1 - 4 x}}$.

Comment: This comes from the recursive formula for the catalan numbers $C_{n+1} = \sum_{k=0}^n C_k\,C_{n-k}$ and a bit manipulation of generating functions